# findViewById throws null exception when it is used on Alert Dialog widgets

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog, findviewbyid

I have a customised alert dialog `layout_dialog.xml`, `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivivty.kt` i am trying to use `findViewById()` in `MainActivity.kt` to get a button and textView from the alert dialog here is a part of my code :

```
tv7 = findViewById(R.id.tv7)
bt4 = findViewById(R.id.bt4)
```

But i am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.tv7) must not be null
```

here is the full error message :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.wordschain, PID: 8398
java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.tv7) must not be null
    at com.example.wordschain.MainActivity.create_Alert_Dialog(MainActivity.kt:83)
    at com.example.wordschain.MainActivity.do1(MainActivity.kt:318)
    at com.example.wordschain.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:48)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6329)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25002)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

Note : i am getting this messages in debugging mode.

EDIT : here i am sharing the `layout_dialog.xml` snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You lost with score"
        android:background="@color/Red2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Restart"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bt4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Or watch an Ad and continue with 2 chances"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Watch Ad"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is where i used the `findViewById()` in the main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Some code ....
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //Some code ...
        }
    fun create_Alert_Dialog(How: Int){
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null)
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(messageBoxView)
    //Setting undissmissable
    messageBoxBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    //Show
    messageBoxBuilder.show()
    tv7 = findViewById(R.id.tv7)
    bt4 = findViewById(R.id.bt4)
    bt4.setOnClickListener { Lose() }
}
```

Comment: post layout_dialog.xml code and code snippet of where you are calling tv7 = findViewById(R.id.tv7)

Comment: Share your layout file and code snippet

Comment: I shared them and (Note : i am using data binding in activity_main.xml)

Comment: I wonder how this code is compiling!

Comment: My app has more than 400 lines of code i can't share them all here they will just make the things slower and harder i just posted the relevent part of the code

Comment: Show us this specific line of your code. It is where the problem is occurring : MainActivity.kt:83 and MainActivity.kt:48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
tv7 = findViewById(R.id.tv7)
bt4 = findViewById(R.id.bt4)
```

With this:

```
tv7 = messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.tv7)
bt4 = messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.bt4)
```

You are inflating a view (the dialog) into your activity with:

```
val messageBoxView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null)
```

You then need to define tv7 and bt4 views, but they are in the view that you inflated previously. So you need to define them based on the inflated view.

Answer (score 1):

The element with id **tv7** is not inside the activity, it is present in the dialogs view. **messageBoxView** is your dialogs inflated view. So any view you want to access inside that layout has to be under its reference.

**tv7 = messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.tv7)**

**bt4 = messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.bt4)**